# changing values ​​in a distribution without changing the average

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, average

I have a set of positive values and I need to increase or decrease this set by adding or reducing number of values. But I would like the mean of values is not altered much.

Example:
I have this array {1,1,1,1,1,2,4,4,15,20} size is 10 
I need size 8 or 16 (I always need pow of two)  so not to alter too, I prefer to delete two values in this array, instead reaching size 16. How I chose this two value ?? The average may change a little bit, but not too.

Comment: If you delete two 4s, the mean will be 5.25, the closest to the original.

Comment: Please retag this question to "Probability-distribution". "Distribution-theory" is meant for generalized functions.

Answer (score 1):

Let say our set of values is $S=\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n\}$. You should look for values $x,y\in S$ such that have closest average to the average of the set:
$$\min_{x,y}|\frac{x+y}{2}-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^na_i|$$
This is what I mean: the average of $\{1,1,1,1,1,2,4,4,15,20\}$ is 5, so the perfect choice would be such $x,y$ that $\frac{x+y}{2}=5$, in this case we take $4,4$, because any other pair would have average further from 5 than 4

Comment: thank you julius, you know some algorthm that do this ? My set can have 100 values too, and in this case, I must reach 128, so I add 28 values...

Comment: If I remove one value at time, removing value that minimize the change of avarage at each step, and repeat until the size is correct, is this a valid approach ??